# What is the difference between types of chests?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far, I've seen normal Chests, Bloody Chests, Treasure Chests, Exquisite Chests, Resplendent Chests, and Cursed Chests. Normal Chests seem just that, and the Resplendent Chests drop quite a bit more/better loot.

What are all the chests are out there, and is there anything special about them? Both Exquisite and Resplendent chests glow yellow, so I assume they have some different drop rate - do the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This answer is updated as of the Reaper of Souls expansion.**

**While it's important to realize the random nature of the game and it's drops**, here are some general observations I have made in my playthroughs. Keep in mind, your experience may vary:

- **Resplendent and Exquisite chests** have dropped by far the most
  gold/gems/rare loot in my playthroughs. It is common for me to find a couple rares, a good loot haul, a couple gems, and very occasionally a legendary item. Of all the chests, **these are the only ones that I have seen a consistent increase in the quality and quantity of drops** to conclusively distinguish them from any other chest. Couple that with the special sound effects they make when opened, and the fact they appear much more infrequently, and one can discern they have elevated loot.
- **Cursed Chests** operate in the exact same manner as resplendent and exquisite chests once the curse on them has been lifted. When you find a cursed chest, there is generally a short event you have to fight your way through to lift the curse. The events range from killing an elite mob that spawns nearby, killing a certain number of enemies within a time limit, or simply surviving a a few waves of enemies. In some cases, you can improve your loot by meeting certain pre-requisites, which will be outlined for you in your quest pane.
- **Normal Chests** are all other containers that behave as a chest would. For example, bloody chests, treasure chests, demonic vessels, etc. are considered "chests" for game purposes and have random loot. Depending on your level, you will generally get one or two pieces of gear of varying quality, as well as a modest gold haul. Sometimes you will get gems. It should be noted however, that like any container, even a normal chest has a chance to drop legendary items.

Important to remember though, **if you can interact with it, CLICK IT**. You never know what will come out. On multiple occasions I have received a rare or even a legendary item from an innocuous environmental object or a large sum of gold from a dead soldier. If you value loot, it pays to be a completionist. Explore every nook and cranny of each map and kill or demo everything. It will keep you ahead of the leveling curve, and ensure you maximize earning potential in each area.

Comment: It's not really in the same category, but there is also the *single*(that I know of) Mysterious Chest

Comment: I don't think this post is correct. I've seen no such correlation between loot and chest type that you describe. Instead, bloody chests, normal chests, treasure chests, etc. seem to be in one category ("normal chests") and only seem to change based on the location where you are, e.g. bloody chests are where you find the goat men, treasure chests in the desert, etc. If you write something like this, you should actually test it(put on 0 magic find and find a lot of chests, record the data) instead of just claiming things based on anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @heishe - What kind of test are you suggesting when we know the results to be random? Anyone who plays through the game a couple of times can tell you that Resplendent/Exquisite chests have an elevated chance to provide good loot, while the other normal chests typically are not that rewarding. Unlike the other "normal" chests however, I have yet to get anything decent out of a bloody chest, and decided it was worth noting.

Comment: If possible, can this answer be updated to include the new Cursed chests, their events, and rewards if successfully completing the event (or result of a failure)?

Comment: I can update it, but to say I know all the different events surrounding cursed chests would be false. I can add them to the list though.

Comment: @heishe- you were right, over time i began to see less and less difference between all other chests in the game that were not exquisite/respelendent/cursed. These are all considered "normal" chests.

Comment: @Tater596 I meant more of the fact that they *have* events rather than what all the possible events necessarily were.  You're edited answer is perfectly fine, thanks!